# Can I change the order of the search results in the Windows 7 start menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

Is it possible to change the sort order of the search results in the Windows 7 start menu? I'd like to either have them completely unsorted by the type of result they are or have files appear before outlook emails.

I tend to use the search to find files that I want to open much more than searching for emails.

Comment: Disabling the items you do not want (e.g. turning off that that search finds programs and/or Control Panel applets) isn't an option for you I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a custom sort being done by Windows itself. I've never seen any options to adjust it outside of marking which files you want indexed and which one you don't.

Answer (score 1):

*In the Windows 7 Search box*:

- Enter your search keyword
- Select "See more details"
- then in the Search windows choose the display "details" (icon in the
  right corner)
- right click to see more columns options and choose the ones you want
- finally sort them by column according to the column label (by type
  acces date, etc. for example)...

  [image]

If you want more control on your search may I suggest you to try Agent Ransack as an alternative search utility? http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home

Hope this help. Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat (until it's on top) this for the icon which you want to appear on top:

1. press the windows key
2. search for the thing you want (always search for the same phrase, for the one for which you want your app/icon to appear for on top)
3. click on it to open

I think that it orders by the number of times you clicked on it when searching for a phrase...